# how can I remove gray outline that insists on appearing on my logo when refreshing pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, elementor

(Update)
Problem 50% solved! It seems it comes from the PNG file. Once I changed it for a SVG file, the "glitch" does not appear anymore. BUT, now I have another problem (lol).

**How do I get this SVG file to respond to my code as the PNG did before?**
This is the code that I used to make my PNG shrink when scrolling. But it does not work with the SVG (even if I named it as ".logo" too).

**Anyone knows what I have to change in the CSS code to make the SVG respond to it, please? :)**

```css
.logo img {
max-width: 110px;
height: auto;
transition: all 1s ease;
}


.elementor-sticky--effects .logo img {
max-width: 80px;
height: auto;
}
```

I guess it's easier to understand my problem with images:

This is the homepage (image 1). When I refresh it or if I go to the other pages, an annoying gray outline contours the logo (image2), like a glance, and then disappears. Do you guys know how to remove this thing?

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8uyo.jpg)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbBm0.jpg)

I added an additional CSS code on elementor pro so it started happening....This is the code:

```css
selector.elementor-sticky--effects{
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7)!important
}

selector{
transition: background-color 1s ease !important;
}

selector.elementor-sticky--effects >.elementor-container{
min-height: 70px;
}

selector > .elementor-container{
transition: min-height 1s ease !important;
}

.logo img {
max-width: 110px;
height: auto;
transition: all 1s ease;
}

}

.elementor-sticky--effects .logo img {
max-width: 90px;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Show the html for this image

Comment: https://mfitie.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/logo_mfitie_SVG-01.svg

Comment: Do you use `src` attribute?

Comment: No, I did not use it on this SVG file. Why, should I? thanks

Comment: How can I know what html tag you use?

Answer (score 0):

```
.logo img {
max-width: 110px;
height: auto;
transition: all 1s ease;
border: transparent;
}
```

Try border transparent

Comment: Hello Patricia,
Unfortunately it didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Try add 0px in border like this

```
.logo img {
max-width: 110px;
height: auto;
transition: all 1s ease;
border: 0px;
}
```

hope this'll help

Comment: It didn't solve the problem, neither. Actually I don't think it is a border problem, since it does not happen on desktop version. It only happens on mobile (safari, firefox and chrome). 

Maybe something related to the mobile version when charging?